# Special characters in Luis intent name

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have an intent named: `"Smalltalk.greetings.how_are_you"`

[image]

When I run a Luis query, the json responses gives `"Smalltalk_greetings_how_are_you"`

Why so ?
If this intended please refer to the documentation explaining why and to use special characters as intent name because I really need to do so.

Comment: Is there some reason that this creates a problem for you? I agree it's strange to have this discrepancy between LUIS UI and what is returned, but knowing that can't you account for it now?

Comment: Do you consider my answer appropriate? If so, please "accept" and upvote it so others can quickly find the answer and I can clear this from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to documentation on this is [found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-boundaries#object-naming). However, it doesn't specifically mention periods.

I'll file a bug report/feature request to add some documentation on this.

My guess is that LUIS replaces all separator characters with underscores for consistency. There may be some trouble parsing some due to the various ways the JSON gets serialized and deserialized.

That being said, as you're now aware of the behavior, I'd either account for it in your code or change your intent names in LUIS. If you're worried about this happening with other intent names, you could use RegEx matching in your code when you look for intents.

I know, not ideal, but the only part of this that's likely to change is updated documentation, which I'll put a request in for.